# Pwa studio adding custom css

Tags: css, pwa, pwa-studio

I'm learning pwa studio how to code

here is the code:

/* src/components/GreetingPage/greetingPage.js */

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { string, number, shape } from 'prop-types';
import {Form} from "informed";
//import classes from "../../overwrites/components/gallery/test.css";
import Field from "../../../../venia-ui/lib/components/Field";
import TextInput from "../../../../venia-ui/lib/components/TextInput";
import defaultClasses from "./greetingPage.css";
import {useStyle} from "@magento/venia-ui/lib/classify";

const hi = {
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: "1rem",
};
const wave = {
    ...hi,
    fontSize: "5rem",
};

const GreetingPage = props => {
    const { who = "nobody" } = useParams();
    const classes = useStyle(defaultClasses, props.classes);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 style={hi}>Hello, {who}!</h1>
            <h1 style={wave}>{"\uD83D\uDC4B"}</h1>

            <Form
                initialValues=""
            >
                <div>
                    <Field
                        id="lastname"

                    >
                        <div>
                            <label className={classes.inputCss}>Last Name:</label>
                            <TextInput
                                field="lastname"
                                className={classes.inputCss}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Field>
                </div>
            </Form>
        </div>

    );
};

export default GreetingPage;
```

/*src/components/GreetingPage/greetingPage.css*/

```
.labelCss {
    float: left;
    color: red;
}

.inputCss {
    float: left;
    color: red;
}
```

the above code didn't work, the class name not adding in the  tag in frontend, do anyone know how to do that?

Comment: className='inputCss' work now, but i don't understand why can't use like className={classes.inputCss}

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below example for your reference.

/src/lib/components/Button/button.js

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { useButton } from 'react-aria';
import { oneOf, shape, string, bool } from 'prop-types';

import { useStyle } from '@magento/venia-ui/lib/classify';
import defaultClasses from './button.module.css';

const getRootClassName = (priority, negative) =>
    `root_${priority}Priority${negative ? 'Negative' : ''}`;

/**
 * A component for buttons.
 *
 * @typedef Button
 * @kind functional component
 *
 * @param {props} props React component props
 *
 * @returns {React.Element} A React component that displays a single button.
 */
const Button = props => {
    const {
        children,
        classes: propClasses,
        priority,
        negative,
        disabled,
        onPress,
        ...restProps
    } = props;

    const buttonRef = useRef();

    const { buttonProps } = useButton(
        {
            isDisabled: disabled,
            onPress,
            ...restProps
        },
        buttonRef
    );

    const classes = useStyle(defaultClasses, propClasses); // here add your class variable 
    const rootClassName = classes[getRootClassName(priority, negative)];

    return (
        <button
            ref={buttonRef}
            className={rootClassName}
            {...buttonProps}
            {...restProps}
        >
            <span className={classes.content}>{children}</span> <!-- use class variable -->
        </button>
    );
};
```

/src/lib/components/Button/button.module.css

```
.content {
    margin: 0;
    align-items: center;
    display: inline-grid;
    gap: 0.35rem;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you can rename your CSS file name like
**greetingPage.css** to
**greetingPage.module.css** and call your CSS into your src/components/GreetingPage/greetingPage.js file.